# Can share files in 'Public' folder, but not folders

Tags: finder, permission, user-account, sharing

I have two user accounts on one Mac, and am trying to share a folder from one to the other.

I put the folder into my Public folder and set the permissions to 'everyone' and 'apply enclosed'.

When I login to the other user account and try to copy the folder, I can't access it.

I've also tried copying the individual sub-folders but they are all blocked too.

I *can* however copy *files*... but it will take forever going through every subfolder and grabbing all the different files.

Also I *cannot overwrite* the files, even when I copy them to my desktop.

Am I doing something wrong? Could this be in some way related to the fact that I'm using OneDrive?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Public isn't really meant for this type of task; that's what Shared is for. Public is for people to be able to read things, & a special drop box folder to send things to that user. Shared is… for things that are shared. [I mean, you *can* start stomping around adding ACLs here, there & everywhere, but you're trying to achieve something which is already set up for you in Shared.]

Comment: @tetsujin Thank you!